# Failing at attempt to reference text within a page using xpath and javascript from a custom Firefox extension/add-on

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, firefox-addon

I have been having issues with this for several days and have been searching all over StackOverflow and Google for the answer.  This is code within a Firefox extension which I am referencing a label/text on a webpage.  I am trying to get the text from the middle of `<b></b>` tags.  The test is deep within a document so I figured I might be able to use xpath to reference it.  I have been attempting to use the document.evaluate function to reference this with no luck.  Here is the code snippet that I have most recently tried:

```
var result = document.evaluate( '//*[@id="page"]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/b', document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null );
alert( 'Value: ' + result.stringvalue );
```

I am new to DOM and xpath so please let me know if this is at least on the right track.  I have tried other methods as well with little success.  The HTML code I'm trying to pull this out of looks like the following:

```
.
. Rest of the source
.
<b>This is title number 8955592</b>
.
.
```

I got the xpath from the chrome inspect element feature.  I have also tried using firebug to see if anything in there would help as well.

Xpath:

```
//*[@id="page"]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/b
```

CSSPath:

```
#page > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr:nth-child(9) > td:nth-child(2) > b
```

My hope is that I have a simple formatting error in my xpath string which I am just starting the string wrong.  This same issue forced me to stop another project I was working on so I decided that I would try and actually address it this time.  I must re-enforce that this is part of a firefox extension I am working on.  I also looked into nodes as a way to do this but that got complicated pretty fast.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I also tried to make this xpath as simple as possible and this did not work as well.  The following would be the xpath starting from the html tags:     

`/html/body/div/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/b`

Comment: You mentioned failing and no luck. What result are you actually getting? I.e. what does the alert show as the result.stringvalue?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant portion of the web page you're trying to extract data from?

Comment: I was getting a undefined result.  When I took off the .stringValue from the end the result was a _XPathResult_ object.  I later determined that you can do a .singleNodeValue on a _XPathResult_ object and get the actual _HTMLElement_ object you are trying to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have

```
result.stringvalue
```

which should be

```
result.stringValue
```

(capital V). However, this should throw an error. I assume you have checked the console for errors?

Without seeing the page you're trying to extract data from, it's hard to say what's going wrong. But you could narrow it down as follows:

```
var result = document.evaluate(
  '//*[@id="page"]', // /table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/b',
  document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
```

What I've done is just take the first part of the XPath expression and comment out the rest for now. I also asked for a node result type. Then see how many nodes are returned:

```
console.log(result.snapshotLength); // or alert() if you prefer
```

If the `//*[@id="page"]` expression yields 1 or more results, then extend the expression and try again:

```
 var result = document.evaluate(
  '//*[@id="page"]/table[3]', // /tbody/tr/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/b',
  document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
```

and again check the result.snapshotLength.
When you get a zero for snapshotLength, that's the point where your XPath is failing. And that should help you figure out why. But if you can't figure out why, show us those results and we'll see if we can help.

Comment: I was able to get this working thanks to your post.  Your help was much appreciated.  I had to do the following to get this to work properly:
`document.evaluate( '//*[@id="page"]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/b', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue.innerHTML;`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help everyone. I finally figured this out, I apologize for the late response. I did misspell stringValue and however I didn't end up using this property. I was able to move forward in this and figure it out given the recommendations provided. I was getting a undefined result initially. When I took off the .stringValue from the end the result was a *XPathResult* object. I later determined that you can do a .singleNodeValue on a *XPathResult* object and get the actual *HTMLElement* object you are trying to work with.  Here is the end result I eventually used to resolve this:

`document.evaluate( '//*[@id="page"]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/b', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue.innerHTML;`

Which returns the contents of the `<b>text</b>` from the page. Even though this may look like a tedious way of getting this result, figuring this out basically taught me how these objects work which I didn't understand when I first asked this question. Using a systematic way to track if I am on the right path (as recommended) was extremely helpful. Again, thank you very much for your assistance.